# Problems with redirecting console input in java

Tags: java

I am having trouble redirecting input from the console to a GUI in Java.

I have received an assignment, to build a Java command based game. That game includes i.e. the `Parser` and `Console` classes. The `Parser` is used to recognize commands, and `Console` is a graphical representation of a console.

The `Parser` class are using `System.in` and `Scanner()` to read the commands.

The `Console` class are redirecting the input from a `jTextArea` object by using `System.setIn()`.

The `Parser` works fine with Intellij console and Windows cmd, but the `Parser` does not receive the text line when I redirect the input. What am I doing wrong?

**The code in a test version.**

Just run the `Console` class to open the console window. In the window type a word and press Enter. If it works, you will see your word repeated twice in the window below your word. If it doesn't work, your word will only be repeated once  below your word.

Console:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter;
import javax.swing.text.Highlighter.HighlightPainter;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Console implements KeyListener, ActionListener {
    final String title = "World of Plastic";
    final int width = 1380;
    final int height = 750;

    final String font = "Consolas";
    final int fontSize = 12;
    final int fontStyle = Font.PLAIN;

    final JTextArea jta;
    final HighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.gray);

    int initialCaretPosition = 0;

    // key codes
    final int BACKSPACE = 8;
    final int ENTER = 10;
    final int PG_UP = 33;
    final int PG_DN = 34;
    final int END = 35;
    final int HOME = 36;
    final int LEFT_ARROW = 37;
    final int UP_ARROW = 38;
    final int RIGHT_ARROW = 39;
    final int DOWN_ARROW = 40;

    final int A = 65;
    final int H = 72;

    public Console() {
        JFrame jf = this.frame();

        //*** JTextArea ***//
        this.jta = this.textArea("", 1, 1, false);

        this.jta.addKeyListener(this);

        // remove all mouse listeners
        for (MouseListener listener : this.jta.getMouseListeners()) {
            this.jta.removeMouseListener(listener);
        }

        // remove all mouse motion listeners
        for (MouseMotionListener listener : this.jta.getMouseMotionListeners()) {
            this.jta.removeMouseMotionListener(listener);
        }

        // remove all mouse wheel listeners
        for (MouseWheelListener listener : this.jta.getMouseWheelListeners()) {
            this.jta.removeMouseWheelListener(listener);
        }

        //*** Scrollable JTextArea ***//
        jf.add(this.scrolls(15, 15, this.width - 45, this.height - 70));

        jf.setVisible(true);

        System.setOut(new Interceptor(System.out, this));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Console cfjp = new Console();

        //new Game().play();

        // A simpel parser
        while (true) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("> ");
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("parser " + reader.nextLine());
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        System.out.println("actionPerformed");
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
        int keyCode = ke.getKeyCode();

        if (keyCode == PG_UP || keyCode == PG_DN || keyCode == UP_ARROW || keyCode == DOWN_ARROW) {
            ke.consume();
        } else if (keyCode == A && ke.getModifiersEx() == InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK) {
            //this.highlightText(this.getStartCaretPosition(), this.getEndCaretPosition());
            ke.consume();
        } else if (keyCode == HOME) {
            this.setCaretPosition(this.getStartCaretPosition());
            ke.consume();
        } else if (keyCode == END) {
            this.setCaretPosition(this.getEndCaretPosition());
            ke.consume();
        } else if (keyCode == RIGHT_ARROW || keyCode == LEFT_ARROW || keyCode == BACKSPACE ||
                (keyCode == H && ke.getModifiersEx() == InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK)) {
            int pos = this.getCaretPosition();
            if (pos <= this.getStartCaretPosition() || pos >= this.getEndCaretPosition()) {
                ke.consume();
            }
        } else if (keyCode == ENTER) {
            int from = this.getStartCaretPosition();
            int to = this.getEndCaretPosition();

            this.setStartCaretPosition(to);

            try {
                String inputFromUser = this.jta.getText(from, to - from);
                System.out.println("\ninputFromUser " + inputFromUser.trim());
                ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream((inputFromUser).getBytes());
                System.setIn(bais);

                //System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream("5".getBytes()));
                //System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(inputFromUser.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
        } else if (this.getCaretPosition() < this.getStartCaretPosition()) {
            this.setCaretPosition(this.getEndCaretPosition());
        }
    }

    public int getCaretPosition() {
        return this.jta.getCaretPosition();
    }

    public void setCaretPosition(int position) {
        this.jta.setCaretPosition(position);
    }

    public int getStartCaretPosition() {
        return this.initialCaretPosition;
    }

    public void setStartCaretPosition(int position) {
        this.setCaretPosition(position);
        this.initialCaretPosition = position;
    }

    public int getEndCaretPosition() {
        return this.jta.getDocument().getLength();
    }

    public void print(String text) {
        this.jta.append(text);
        this.setStartCaretPosition(this.getEndCaretPosition());
    }

    public JFrame frame() {
        JFrame tmpJF = new JFrame(this.title);

        tmpJF.setSize(this.width, this.height);
        tmpJF.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        tmpJF.setLayout(null);
        tmpJF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tmpJF.setResizable(false);

        return tmpJF;
    }

    public JTextArea textArea(String text, int rows, int columns, boolean lineWrap) {
        JTextArea tmpJTA = new JTextArea(text, rows, columns);

        tmpJTA.setEditable(true);
        tmpJTA.setLineWrap(lineWrap);
        tmpJTA.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        tmpJTA.setFont(new Font(this.font, this.fontStyle, this.fontSize));
        tmpJTA.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        tmpJTA.setBackground(Color.black);

        return tmpJTA;
    }

    public JScrollPane scrolls(int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JScrollPane tmpJSP = new JScrollPane(this.jta);

        tmpJSP.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        tmpJSP.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        tmpJSP.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        return tmpJSP;
    }
}
```

Interceptor:

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Interceptor extends PrintStream {
    private final Console obj;

    public Interceptor(OutputStream out, Console obj) {
        super(out, true);
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void print(boolean b) {
        this.obj.print(String.valueOf(b));
    }

    @Override
    public void print(char c) {
        this.obj.print(String.valueOf(c));
    }

    @Override
    public void print(char[] s) {
        this.obj.print(Arrays.toString(s));
    }

    @Override
    public void print(double d) {
        this.obj.print(String.valueOf(d));
    }

    @Override
    public void print(float f) {
        this.obj.print(String.valueOf(f));
    }

    @Override
    public void print(int i) {
        this.obj.print(String.valueOf(i));
    }

    @Override
    public void print(long l) {
        this.obj.print(String.valueOf(l));
    }

    @Override
    public void print(Object obj) {
        if (obj != null) {
            this.obj.print(obj.toString());
        }
        this.obj.print("null");
    }

    @Override
    public void print(String s) {
        this.obj.print(String.valueOf(s));
    }

    @Override
    public void println() {
        this.obj.print("\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void println(boolean x) {
        this.obj.print(x + "\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void println(char x) {
        this.obj.print(x + "\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void println(char[] x) {
        this.obj.print(Arrays.toString(x) + "\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void println(double x) {
        this.obj.print(x + "\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void println(float x) {
        this.obj.print(x + "\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void println(int x) {
        this.obj.print(x + "\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void println(long x) {
        this.obj.print(x + "\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void println(Object x) {
        if (x != null) {
            this.obj.print(x.toString() + "\n");
        }
        this.obj.print("null\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void println(String x) {
        this.obj.print(x + "\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that with

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream((inputFromUser).getBytes());
System.setIn(bais);
```

you replace the `System.in` InputStream, but your code in `main`

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("parser " + reader.nextLine());
```

is still waiting on the old `System.in` and therefore never receives any characters.

---

One way to solve it is to create a connected pair of `PipedInputStream` / `PipedOutputStream` and use these:

```
    static PipedOutpuStream out;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream();
        out = new PipedOutputStream();
        in.connect(out);
        System.setIn(in);
        // rest of your main
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
        // much code left out
        try {
            String inputFromUser = this.jta.getText(from, to - from);
            System.out.println("\ninputFromUser " + inputFromUser.trim());
            out.write((inputFromUser + "\n").getBytes());
            out.flush();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
        // much code left out
    }
```

I made `PipedOutputStream out` into a static field because of laziness, you could also pass it as constructor argument into the `Console` constructor.